# Applet with Gui Designer

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, applet

I want to ask you if there is a possibility to program a Java Applet in netbeans 6.5 using the GUI Designer. When I was adding a new file to the source and choose Applet or JApplet, I found now Designer as in a JForm for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to design applets in NetBeans then do this:

1. open a new project
2. right click on "Source Packages"
3. select "New" and "Other"
4. under "Categories" select "Swing GUI Forms" and under "File Types" select "JApplet Form"

Answer (score 2):

To make Designer available make new applet in the following way:

1. Select menu "File \ New File".
2. Select "Swing GUI Forms" from "Categories"
3. Select "JAppletForm" from "File Types" and press "Next".
4. Input desired class name, package name and press "Finish".
5. Now if you select tab with your applet tab you can see two sub-tabs "Source" and "Design". By selecting "Design" you will be able to design you applet.